# calculation of E-K diagram of a charge density wave ground state using DFT VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I have a DFT calculation in VASP are done at 0K. And CDW is a temperature dependent phenomena. Therefore for a CDW ground state calculation can I add periodic modulation in atomic position?

If so how to add periodic modulation to atomic position?

Comment: +1 Welcome to the community. Very often you can identify a charge density wave by performing a phonon calculation of the parent phase and looking for imaginary modes. The eigenvectors of these imaginary modes then give you the required modulation for the CDW.